# Should twitter hashtags be added to questions that are promoted to Twitter?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-promotion, twitter

I think questions would get better visibility if hashtags were added to questions; and to accommodate the longer URL, a tiny URL should be used.

Are there thoughts about adding a pre-tweet review queue that allows for hashtags to be added, along with a shortened URL for sec.se?